# How to plot with the frequency of coincident data taken in consideration of dataframe without using Table function of Base Package

Tags: r, ggplot2

For plotting, I generally use `table` function in Base package which automatically takes care of count and I use in `geom_point` aesthetics (`size = freq`). Is there any alternate to this. Every time I have to individually convert them to `table(x, y)` just to inset count column.

[image: Freq of Galton Dataset]

```
  y <- galton$child - mean(galton$child)
    x <- galton$parent - mean(galton$parent)
    ***freqData <- as.data.frame(table(x, y))***
    names(freqData) <- c("child", "parent", "freq")
    freqData$child <- as.numeric(as.character(freqData$child))
    freqData$parent <- as.numeric(as.character(freqData$parent))
    myPlot <- function(beta){
        g <- ggplot(filter(freqData, freq > 0), aes(x = parent, y = child))
        g <- g  + scale_size(range = c(2, 20), guide = "none" )
        g <- g + geom_point(colour="grey50", aes(size = freq+20, show_guide = FALSE))
}
```

> My Question is Is there any alternate function doing the task what
>   table(x,y) is doing

Comment: can you provide a minimal code example resembling your data frame?

Comment: See [this Q&A on how to include a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: Have you tried `geom_bar(stat="bin")`?

Comment: @shayaa I have edited the question with the code. I guess now you might be able to help me..

Comment: I would like to but please read the Q&A posted above. I am not able to run your code. It needs to include a small data example which your code can run with.